# Why cant I assign a BlockingCollection<T> to IReadOnlyCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Can someone please explain why I get the below compile error? [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the `IReadOnlyCollectio<T>` interface, and there are no issues with the other interfaces. Why the requirement for the explicit cast, and why don't I have to do the same for `List<T>`?

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<string>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<string>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
IReadOnlyCollection<string> roListItems = new List<string>(); // ok (baseline check)

IEnumerable<string> enumBCItems = new BlockingCollection<string>(); // ok
System.Collections.ICollection colBCItems = new BlockingCollection<string>(); // ok
IReadOnlyCollection<string> roBCItems = new BlockingCollection<string>(); // fail
IReadOnlyCollection<string> roExplicitBCItems = (IReadOnlyCollection<string>)new BlockingCollection<string>(); // ok....
```

**Edit**

Below is what resharper was showing me, when I was viewing the declaration, hence my confusion.

```
// Type: System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`1
// Assembly: System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// MVID: BD5F7037-65C4-4C44-8FBC-F45D80D7550F
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.dll

public class BlockingCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ICollection, IDisposable, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
{ ... }
```

Comment: I copied that code block into LinqPad, and it worked fine

Comment: Using the 'other versions' selector, it does not seem as though the class originally implemented `IReadOnlyCollection`. Would guess that you may be using .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It didn't implement that interface in .NET 4.

```
public class BlockingCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable, IDisposable
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: And the 2nd half of the story is .NET 4.5 is a in place upgrade, so even though you target .NET 4.0 the code still runs with .NET 4.5 libraries, that means `IReadOnlyCollection<string> roBCItems = new BlockingCollection<string>()` gives a compiler error but if you do a explicit cast it does not fail with a runtime error.

Comment: @trydis You are correct. Resharper was pulling a number on me. See edit